# Duplicate and rotate JavaFX content within an arc

Tags: javafx

I am attempting to make a JavaFX application which creates Mandalas (a symmetric drawing using geometric patterns squares, triangle, circles). My plan was to allow the user to draw shapes on one arc.  This arc would then be copied and rotated to create the mandala.

Single arc:
[image: completed single arc]

Completed mandala:
[image: completed mandala]

I'm stuck on how to create the finished mandala.  I was thinking layers but how do I set the non arc area of the canvas to be transparent?  Is there a better way to do this?

My code so far is below.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
{
    final double WIDTH = 400;       //constant for canvas size
    final double HEIGHT = 400; 

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Mandala");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    GraphicsContext graphicsContext = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, 
        new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                graphicsContext.beginPath();
                graphicsContext.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                graphicsContext.stroke();
            }
        });

    canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, 
        new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                graphicsContext.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                graphicsContext.stroke();
            }
        });

    canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, 
        new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            }
        });

    int numSegments = 12;
    int numdegrees = 360/numSegments;
    int startAngle = 0;

      //  centreX, centreY, radiuisX (length of lines), radiusY, startAngle (0 is due east), numdegrees
    Arc arc1 = new Arc( 0, 0, 250, 250, startAngle, numdegrees);
    arc1.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
    arc1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    arc1.setFill(null);
    arc1.setStrokeWidth(1);
    root.getChildren().add(arc1);

}
}
```

Comment: Why do you mix canvas drawing primitives with scene graph drawing primitives like [Arc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Arc.html) rather than using canvas graphics context commands like [arcTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#arcTo-double-double-double-double-double-)?

Comment: I'm very new to this so I just found a way that drew the arc!

Answer (score 0):

Use a clip path. This way everything outside the clip path will be ignored. Furthermore `transform` is helpful for drawing rotated objects.

```
private static void piePiece(GraphicsContext context, double width, double height, double radius, double angle) {
    double cx = width / 2;
    double cy = height / 2;
    context.moveTo(cx, cy);
    context.lineTo(cx + radius, cy);
    context.arc(cx, cy, radius, radius, 0, angle);
    context.closePath();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(600, 600);
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    // rotation matrix rotating by 30° around (300, 300)
    Affine rotate = new Affine(new Rotate(30, 300, 300));

    // draw first pie
    gc.beginPath();
    piePiece(gc, 600, 600, 250, 30);
    gc.stroke();

    gc.save();

    // create clip
    gc.beginPath();
    piePiece(gc, 600, 600, 250, 30);
    gc.clip();

    List<List<Point2D>> points = new ArrayList<>();

    Button btn = new Button("Complete");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        // draw data stored in points variable

        // remove old clip
        gc.restore();
        for (int i = 30; i < 360; i += 30) {
            // rotate by 30°
            gc.transform(rotate);

            gc.save();
            // draw piece
            gc.beginPath();
            piePiece(gc, 600, 600, 250, 30);
            gc.stroke();

            // create clip
            gc.beginPath();
            piePiece(gc, 600, 600, 250, 30);
            gc.clip();

            // draw lines
            for (List<Point2D> lines : points) {
                if (lines.size() >= 2) {
                    Iterator<Point2D> iter = lines.iterator();
                    gc.beginPath();
                    Point2D p = iter.next();
                    gc.moveTo(p.getX(), p.getY());
                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                        p = iter.next();
                        gc.lineTo(p.getX(), p.getY());
                    }
                    gc.stroke();
                }

            }
            // remove clip
            gc.restore();
        }
    });

    class PressedHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

        List<Point2D> line;

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (line == null) {
                // add new line to lines list
                line = new ArrayList<>();
                line.add(new Point2D(event.getX(), event.getY()));
                points.add(line);
                gc.beginPath();
                gc.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
        }

    }

    PressedHandler handler = new PressedHandler();

    canvas.setOnMousePressed(handler);
    canvas.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
        if (handler.line != null) {
            // append point to line
            handler.line.add(new Point2D(event.getX(), event.getY()));
            gc.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
        }
    });
    canvas.setOnMouseReleased(event -> {
        // complete line
        handler.line = null;
        gc.stroke();
    });

    VBox root = new VBox(btn, canvas);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Note that the lines are not shown during drawing for simplicity.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had to change a couple of lines as Point2D is an abstract class ie handler.line.add(new Point2D.Double(event.getX(), event.getY()));

Comment: You are importing the wrong class Tortise, you need to use [`javafx.geometry.Point2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Point2D.html), not [`java.awt.geom.Point2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html).  In general, never import AWT or Swing classes into a JavaFX project unless you are sure you need to mix toolkits (which would be highly unusual).